# How to use external javascript/php in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to use a javascript file from an external source on my WordPress site and can't seem to get it to work. It is a specific Captcha I need to include.

The directions from the site are to include the following:

In the HTML include the following:

```
<div data-captcha-enable="true"></div>
```

Add the following JavaScript in the body (site info hidden in asteriks) :

```
<script src="//*site*/captcha.js.php?id=*xxx*"></script>
```

Including both of those in the HTML of a page did not work, and reading into WordPress allowance of scripts it seems this is intentional.

So next I tried to include it in the functions.php through

```
function wpTest_scripts() {
  wp_register_script('captcha', '//*site*/captcha.js.php?id=*xxx*', false);
  wp_enqueue_script( 'captcha' );
 }
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpTest_scripts');
```

I tried a ton of different varieties of this, and including all sorts variations of

```
<script src="//*site*/captcha.js.php?id=*xxx*"></script>
```

in the header, main body etc.

Finally as a last stab I tried to follow advice for allowing scripts in pages within a WordPress site globally.  I know this isn't as secure, but there are no other users of the page and it is a very simple page.  This is also creating an error:

In wp-config.php

```
define( 'CUSTOM_TAGS', true );
```

In functions.php

```
function add_scriptfilter( $string ) {
global $allowedtags;
$allowedtags['script'] = array( 'src' =&gt; array () );
return $string;
}
add_filter( 'pre_kses', 'add_scriptfilter' );
```

This creates an error from the functions.php in this line:

```
$allowedtags['script'] = array( 'src' =&gt; array () );
```

The error is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in

Comment: `=&gt;` should be `=>` ... you are writing code not html entities

Comment: Thanks that did fix the error.  Unfortunately it still doesn't run the javascript.

Comment: I take that back - I can run code just fine now.  Turns out the captcha's JS file is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be just by opening the `footer.php` file of your current active theme.

And pasting the code just before `</body>`

```
    <?php wp_footer(); // and other stuff above ?>
    <script src="//*site*/captcha.js.php?id=*xxx*"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that did not work.